# Adding n number of values to hashmap

Tags: android

In arrayList I can add n number of values like the below code

```
RowOneCollection = new ArrayList<Button>((Arrays.asList(btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4)));
```

Similarly in hash map I am adding n number of vales like this

```
Map<String, String>map= new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("bi","biology");
map.put("ma","maths");
```

like this I am adding n number of values.How I can add all the values in single line like the arraylist

Comment: Then use array list.

Comment: You can put the data using For loop if you have 2 String arrays of Key Value pair.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the data using For loop if you have 2 String arrays consisting of Keys and Values.

```
String[] keys = {"a","aa","aaa"};  //keep both array of same size.
String[] values = {"a1","aa2","aaa3"};
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
for(int i = 0 ; i < keys.length; i++)
{
   map.put(kays[i], values[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to adjust how you are populating your HashMap as follows:

```
HashMap<String,xyz> hMap=new HashMap<String,xyz>();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
  hMap.put("Data"+i, list);
}
```

Where `xyz` is the object,  that you are working with. This approach allows you to take advantage of Java's Generics capability in its Collection objects such as HashMap.